# dummy variable in R for partial string

Tags: r

I am want to create a dummy variable that is 1 if it is contains a part of the numbers. For some reason the str_detect is not working. My error code is as follows:

Error in type(pattern) : argument "pattern" is missing, with no default

```
sam_data_rd$high_int <- as.integer(str_detect(sam_data_rd$assertions.primarynaics,
                                              c("2111", "3254", "3341", "3342", "3344","3345", "3364", "5112", "5171", "51331", 
                                    "5179", "5133Z", "5182", "5191", "5142", "5141Z", "5191Z","5191ZM", "5413", "5415", "5417")))
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern can be a single string with OR (`|`).  Note that the `pattern` is vectorized to allow multiple elements, but the condition is that the `length` of the `pattern` should match the `length` of the `string` (or the column i.e. it will be an elementwise comparison)

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- c("2111", "3254", "3341", "3342", "3344","3345", "3364", "5112", "5171", "51331",                                      "5179", "5133Z", "5182", "5191", "5142", "5141Z", "5191Z","5191ZM", "5413", "5415", "5417")
pat <- str_c("\\b(", str_c(v1, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")

sam_data_rd$high_int <- 
     as.integer(str_detect(sam_data_rd$assertions.primarynaics, pat))
```

---

Or another option is to loop over each of the elements and then `reduce` it to a single logical vector

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
sam_data_rd <- sam_data_rd %>%
     mutate(high_int = map(v1,
    ~ str_detect(assertions.primarynaics, .x)) %>% 
      reduce(`|`) %>% 
      as.integer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

pattern <- paste(c("2111", "3254", "3341", "3342", "3344","3345", "3364", "5112", "5171", "51331", 
                    "5179", "5133Z", "5182", "5191", "5142", "5141Z", "5191Z","5191ZM", "5413", "5415", "5417"), collapse = "|")
sam_data_rd %>% 
  mutate(high_int = ifelse(str_detect(assertions.primarynaics, pattern), 1, assertions.primarynaics)
```

Comment: that didn't generate a new variable in my dataframe.

Comment: Could you provide `str` info.